# Plotting in widget on ui with PySide6

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, pyside6

I need to plot on the predefined part of the ui with PySide6.
The ui is designed with Qt Creator and it contains a widget called "widgetGraph". If I'm using the following example it works, but due to the set of the central widget everything on the ui gets overwritten

```
self.ui.widgetGraph = pyqtgraph.PlotWidget()
self.ui.setCentralWidget(self.ui.widgetGraph)

hour = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
temperature = [30,32,34,32,33,31,29,32,35,45]

# plot data: x, y values
self.ui.widgetGraph.plot(hour, temperature)
```

Without using the "setCentralWidget" function the widget remains empty.
Is there any way not to override the ui elements, just plot into the previously mentioned "widgetGraph" widget?

Comment: You need to add the widget to a [layout manager](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) (you can add them in [Designer too](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html) if you've not done it yet - and you should).

Comment: How do you mean exactly?
Every item on the ui is set in different layouts, so directly under the central widget in the designer is a vertical layout right now

Comment: Then add the plot widget to any of those layouts using `self.ui.someLayout.addWidget(self.ui.widgetGraph)`.

Comment: This is it! Works like charm. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. Please don't edit a question to add an answer. Use the "Answer your question" button if you find a valid solution that justifies an answer to be added (or that provides more insights), otherwise if comments are clear enough you can just leave it to those. In this specific case I doubt that there should be need for that, as the "answer" is simple enough and is already covered by lots of other posts or by sufficient studying of the documentation (but nobody will blame you if you want to do it anyway). Please take your time to review the [tour], and read [ask] and [answer].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the answer from *@musicamante*, the plot widget has to added to the layout with the following code:

```
self.ui.someLayout.addWidget(self.ui.widgetGraph)
```